# Mars Ecliptic Latitude

Tags: mars, ecliptic

It's stated Mars orbital plane is 1.8 degree to the ecliptic.

How then can Mars can ecliptic latitude went beyond 1.8 ?
Example; Jan 8th 2023, Mars latitude at +2.8. 24th Jan 2025, +4.3.

Isn't the concept of ecliptic latitude means how much Mars is above the ecliptic.

Answer (score 4):

The angle MSP is the inclination of Mars relative to the ecliptic plane. This is 1.851 degrees

The angle MEP is the Ecliptic latitude of Mars from Earth.  This angle can be greater than 1.851 degrees.

```
                                M

S-----------------E--------------P
```

S is the sun E is the Earth, M is Mars and SP is the plane of the ecliptic in this cross-section view.

Comment: Thanks alot.1.8 is heliocentric and geocentric is more.